# Auto detect delimiter in CSV using Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I am using Apache Commons CSV for parsing CSV files.
My application use two type of CSVs with similar headers, one with comma (,) as separator and other has semi colon (;) as separator.

Is there any way to autodetect separator in CSV files using Apache Commons CSV?

Comment: Not out of the box as far as I see. You could start to parse with both formats and use the one which leads to more headers.

Comment: @centic
Can you help me in parsing with both formats. My application has file as only input without any extra parameter or input.